# Problem in switching MOSFETs in brushless motor drive

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, switching, mosfet-driver, motordriver

I have designed a brushless motor drive, the schematic below shows the connection of gate drive and MOSFETs:
[image: schematic]

In general, the drive works well, but there are some problems with the switching of the MOSFETs.

As shown in the picture below, U-phase MOSFETs cause a short circuit at the moment of shutdown, which causes the MOSFETs to become extremely hot at high currents and destroy the MOSFETs (Miller effect). The blue waveform corresponds to the upper MOSFETs and the yellow waveform corresponds to the lower MOSFETs.

U-phase, gate-source waveform:

[image: U-phase gate-source waveform]

This problem only happens to the U phase and as shown in the figure below, the W phase does not have this problem:

W-phase, gate-source waveform:

[image: W-phase gate-source waveform]

I tried many methods but none of them worked like putting a capacitor in series with the gate resistor or putting a p-channel MOSFET between the gate and source of MOSFET.

Can anyone help? Why does this happen only for the U phase??

Comment: In spite of your description, it's not clear where the scope probes are set up.  Could you call these out explicitly -- i.e., "Q1 gate, Q1 source".  Is whatever you're driving the IR2101 with providing some dead time, and you're seeing shoot-through _anyway_, or are you not providing dead time?

Comment: I'm not seeing any deadtime from when you turn off the FET to when you turn on the corresponding FET in the same half bridge.  This causes shoot through while both the top and bottom FETs are on at the same time.  Add this and you should be good.

Comment: @TimWescott The blue signal corresponds to Q1 and the yellow signal corresponds to Q2. Also, these signals are from the connection of the oscilloscope probes to the gate and source of the MOSFETs. Also I have set the dead time to 2500 ns

Comment: Looks to me like you have an issue with your MCU. There is 5us dead time on the left hand side transition and 0us dead time on the right side. What are you driving it with? MCU? Have you set your timers up wrong? Are you even using timers? If it happens on one phase but not the other, clearly there is a difference between the phases. This would imply that the schematic you have provided is not the source of the problem, and adding different caps, resistors whatever... is futile.

Comment: @DavidMolony I am using stm32f103c8, I have observed pwm output through oscilloscope, everything is good and dead time is set correctly

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this earlier -- you're a newbie to StackExchange.  Could you _edit your question_ with the information about the circuit nodes you're probing?  StackExchange really prefers that information like this be edited into the questions (and answers) rather than buried in comments.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is with the gate drives?Is it possible to solve the problem if another type of gate drive is used?

Comment: If it is all set correctly, why do you have twice as much dead time on one phase vs the other? How about posting a pic of your setup as well? This is not an issue with the schematic, there is nothing you have provided that can lead us to the correct conclusion. More info required.

Comment: Your schematic shows the sources of the upper legs tied to each other and to the drains of the lower legs. You also show only one output from the bridge.

Comment: @PStechPaul MOSFETs are connected in parallel to withstand high currents, other phases also have a similar schematic.

Comment: In that case, we would need to see the whole schematic. There must be some difference between phases, although if the hardware is identical, it must be due to something in the MCU.